# Roslaunch recursive parsing

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have some code or utility that will let me use 'cat' or 'grep' recursively on ros launch files?  I have launch files that include other launch files, and it can be quite a hunt to find things sometimes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10031/roslaunch-recursive-parsing/) by [baxelrod](https://answers.ros.org/users/86/baxelrod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 794 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's a good feature request.  I went ahead and implemented it in [r13774](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/changeset/13774). You should be able to apply a patch to your tree that does:

roslaunch --files

which will print:

[included files...]

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1